# Unable to run Blender on Ubuntu

Tags: linux

In pretty new to blender, and I installed the latest Ubuntu image on a machine to test it out. When I try to launch it from the console, I get the following error:

```
root@localhost:~# blender
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
Color management: using fallback mode for management
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":11.0".
connect failed: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
AL lib: alsa_open_playback: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":11.0".
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadRenderRequest
  Major opcode of failed request:  148 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  1 (X_GLXRender)
  Serial number of failed request:  310
  Current serial number in output stream:  310
root@localhost:~#
```

Comment: The line containing the error is missing. Please add it to your question.

Comment: Not might not be related to your question, but you shouldn't be running applications like this as `root`. How did you start this session? Looks like you might have done something like `ssh root@localhost`, which would muck things up for X11. Did you try just opening a terminal as your regular user and executing `blender`?

Comment: I just used root because this is a fresh build and I didn't do any configuration like adding user accounts yet. Ill do that and see if it works better under a user account. PS, im using xrdp to access the server from my Windows 7 desktop.

Comment: Can you please tell me where I could go for help? The folks over at linuxquestions told me that it was application specific issue and I had to seek help from Blender folks.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question whether you installed Blender via the command line or by downloading the package.

I'm guessing you installed via the command line as you are encountering dependency issues.

Try downloading the latest release from blender.org, then just double click the executable icon 'blender' in the 'blender-2.7*' folder, or navigate to that directory and from the command line run: ./blender

To reiterate the comment above, you shouldn't be running this as root.

Comment: This was just a throw-together OS just to see if I could get Blender working under ubuntu. Im accessing the system through XRDP from a windows box.  Im new to ubuntu, I work 99% of the time on Centos through command-line, so I don't have any real experience with X-windows or what the errors are trying to tell me. I think there is some package which needs to be installed, and I was hoping someone could identify what's missing.

Comment: Do you know about `apt-get`? Just like Centos `yum`, you can do `apt-get install blender` to get all of the system dependencies.